# Getting jerky backgrounds on Windows 7 on iMac 27'' 2560x1440

Tags: windows-7, mac, graphics-card, colors

I installed Windows 7 on Boot Camp on my new iMac 27'' (ATI videocard) and everything was good until recently I noticed that the default Windows 7 background (then one on the background on login) looked jerky.

When I say jerky I mean the kind of jerky you get if you can't display enough colours, and instead of nice fading shades you just get stripes and jerky patterns. I am on native resolution but even if I go down to 1920x1080 I get the same.

This might have happened after a firmware update but as I don't use Windows very often I am not too sure it's what caused it.

Oh, and when I am playing games everything looks OK (as in not jerky!).

Comment: i don't think *jerky* is the word you're looking for. do you mean something like this http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/be/Dithering_example_undithered_web_palette.png

Comment: yes - not as bad but that's the idea - which word would u suggest?

Comment: When gradients get compression artifacts, they're said to be "banded". When a bitmap gets enlarged beyond its native resolution, it's said to be "jaggy". Are you seeing jaggies, or banding, or both?

Comment: I think I am seeing banding. I get that at very high resolutions the wallpapers could become banded because of the stretch - but I do not get why it was not happening before then but just recently.

Comment: You mentioned a firmware upgrade.  What was this firmware an upgrade for, the Monitor or something else?

Comment: not sure what the firmware update was for - it's just popped up and I said yes :)

Comment: I'd blame the cable, speculating that you just cannot notice that effect while gaming. However, if you only get undesired effects under Windows, my blames have no grounds.

Comment: under MAC-OSX all is good

Comment: this is gone with the latest win7 update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is gone after recent MacOS/Windows 7 updates - not sure exactly which!

Answer (score 2):

Does this happen in windowed applications (i.e., opening a photo)? This is often a sign that your monitor is running at a low depth of color. Banding generally isn't noticeable with 24- or 32-bit color depth, though with 16-bit depth is might be noticeable depending on content, and 8-bit or less will be extremely noticeable with todays applications/themes/pictures.

You can check/set the color depth for windows by going to the control panel -> Display -> Screen Resolution, click "Advanced Settings" -> Monitor Tab. At the bottom there should be a dropdown labelled "Colors:". What is this set to? If it is not set to "True color (32-bit)", try changing it to that.

Fullscreen games probably won't show the banding because they set the color depth when they take over the screen.

If you do not have 32-bit color available (perhaps only 16-bit or less) in the dropdown, I'd look for an update to your graphics drivers (either from ATI or Apple/Bootcamp). If 32-bit color is available and already selected, and other applications show images fine (it's just the login background), I would check that the file hasn't been modified (It's at `C:\Windows\Web\Wallpaper\Windows\img0.jpg` for me) - Right-click -> Properties -> Details -> Image -> Bit Depth (Should be "24").

Comment: that dropdown already says true color (32bit) :(

Comment: @JohnIdol do other images show the banding when you open them in an image viewer?